# how to set the image on CWAC-Camera Fragment

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I am using the CWAC camera library in my application. I tried this and this is working fine showing the camera preview in the relevent Fregment.

Now all I want to past a picture on that camera preview and whenever I click button to take picture it should take picture with that image. I want image in forground and the camera preview in background of it  . So is there any way to do that . [Here](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android_Free_Code/Camera/Download_Free_code_AndroidCamera_App.htm) is the sample code that I am using to take picture

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the CWAC-Camera library. If you want to merge multiple image files together, you are welcome to do so, but you would do that *after* taking the picture.

Comment: so there are many applications , like man suit photo,LondonMansuit and man fashion photo suit , ..........How are they taking camera picture with suit in the front

Comment: @androiddeveloper: They are not "taking camera picture with suit in the front". They are taking a camera picture. They are then super-imposing the suit onto the camera picture.

Comment: then are they doing screen shot?

Comment: @androiddeveloper: Most likely, they are merging two image files.

Comment: can you explain me how they are merging ? please please

Comment: @androiddeveloper: I would imagine that they started by using a search engine, to search for something like `android java merge two images`.